# Is it possible to get the amount of twitter followers asa normal user?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter, counter

**Hello folks!**

I was wondering of it was possible to get only the number of followers from your twitter as plain text, without a button of some sort?

**What I want to do:**
Website: `http://www.sisodevelopment.nl/index2.php`
best viewed in chrome; I started building it today so the twitter and facebook boxes only animate in chrome or safari.

P.S.
I don't mind if it would be xml, js or just php

Kind Regards,

Comment: Been a while since I looked at it, but you should be able to get that from the Twitter API. It's backend work, but doable.

Comment: I know there is now api v1.1 and it needs a auth. file, i have it but when i include it and I try to use a code to get me the data it crashes my page :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a twitter app, after this you will have CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET and you will create the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret in you application.

Then in php you can write a function with this twitteroauth.php included from(https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master/twitteroauth):

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret);
$content = count($connection->get('followers/ids', array('screen_name' => 'twitter_name'))->ids);
return $content;
```

Comment: You gonna need OAuth.php also from the same link

Comment: as I said, as a normal user, so without the app, i know how the app works